# Can't read from text file in C++

Tags: c++, qt, fopen, scanf

Here's my code. I'm using it in a function in QT but the program exits and I don't know why.

```
int xy;
xy = 0;

QVector<double> x(1000), y(1000);
FILE *file;

char line[1024];
file = fopen("ecg.txt", "r");

while (fgets(line,1024,file) != NULL)
{
    fscanf(file,"%d, %d", &y[xy], &x[xy]);
    xy++;
}

QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve;
curve->attach(plot_all[0]);
curve->setData(x,y);
```

I get a segmentation fault in the `while` line

My file only has two doubles per line; they are pairs of coordinates.

I've checked my x and y, and the result is `[0; 0; 0; 0; ...0; 0; 0]`

Comment: Are you sure the call to `fopen` succeeded?

Comment: Do you have a line of text, then two coordinate values?

Comment: no, it's like

x(tab)y

Comment: Your format expects a comma between the two numbers each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass pointers to `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf(file,"%d, %d", &y[xy], &x[xy]);
```

Also, since `x` and `y` are vectors of `double`, you need to use `%lf` to read the values.    You should also check the return value from `fscanf()` to ensure that two values were read successfully:

```
if (fscanf(file, "%lf, %lf", &x[xy], &y[xy]) != 2)
    ...handle error...
```

You need to turn on compilation warnings and fix what the compiler warns about — or get a better compiler that gives you such warnings (`g++ -Wall` is a good start if you use G++).

Note, too, that this curious code reads a line into `line`, then reads some numbers direct from the file.  Did you mean to write:

```
if (sscanf(line, "%lf, %lf", &x[xy], &y[xy]) != 2)
    ...handle error...
```

What you've got will have `fgets()` read the first line (assuming nothing longer than 1 KiB), then the `fscanf()` will read the first two numbers on a line, and the next iteration of `fgets()` will read the residue of the line, leaving `fscanf()` to find the numbers on the next line.  Unusual, but a feasible scheme.

In a comment, you say that the format on each line is `x`<kbd>tab</kbd>`y`; if that's the case and there is no comma separating the values, then you need to remove the comma from the format string:

```
if (sscanf(line, "%lf %lf", &x[xy], &y[xy]) != 2)
    ...handle error...
```

However, if your crash really is happening in the `while` line, then your problem is almost certainly that the file failed to open.  Always check the return from `fopen()` (or any other file-opening function).  You can fail to open a file for many, many reasons and blundering on assuming that the file opened when it didn't never leads to happiness.

Also, in C++, it is a good idea to initialize variables as you define them:

```
FILE *file = fopen("ecg.txt", "r");

if (file == 0)
    ...handle error...

QVector<double> x(1000), y(1000);
char line[1024];
int xy = 0;
```

Comment: the file is in the same path as my program. with the same name as in the code. but I think it is not opening.

Comment: Thnaks, the x value is now ok, but as the separation between x and y in the file is not a space but a tab, I can't read the y.

Comment: See my comments about the comma in the format string; you don't want it unless your values are separated by a comma.  If you captured the return value from `fscanf()` or `sscanf()` — for example, with `int n = fscanf(...);` — you could print it out and see that you were getting 1 returned.